# Can deleted files be overwritten by new files with the same name?

Tags: backup

By default CrashPlan keeps deleted files for ever.

Would a deleted file stored in the CrashPlan backup be overwritten if I create another file with the same path?

Example scenario:

1. I create `test.txt`
2. CrashPlan backup runs
3. I delete `test.txt`
4. CrashPlan backup runs
5. I create a new `test.txt` with different content
6. CrashPlan backup runs

Is it possible to restore the first `test.txt` from the CrashPlan backup now?

Comment: it depends entirely on how full your disk is, and your type of filesystem. If the disk is quite full, then yes the data is likely overwritten. Disks attempt a degree of "sparseness" in that they don't try to fill each consecutive block, but instead leave some gaps, to help prevent fragmentation later on if the file in the preceding block grows. That implies that if there is plenty of room, the data should still be where you left it. there is no relationship between disk block address and file location in the file system hierarchy.

Comment: @FrankThomas this is about CrashPlan not filesystems. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @developerbmw - Questions on how Crashplan functions behind the scenes are not on topic here at Superuser.  Needless to say there are any number of ways Crashplan can handle this, one of those ways is they keep multiple versions of a file ( might not be enable by default).  Crashplan is more or less a web application or service, how the client works would be on topic, or the file is actually stored not so much in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated to Web Apps. Crashplan isn't any more on-topic here.

Comment: I knew that, hence the reason, no vote to migrate from me :$

Comment: Can we close this question as off-topic?

Comment: It wouldn't be so off-topic if it wasn't moved erroneously